# Measure code coverage lost from removing some tests in Ruby

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, code-coverage

I'm thinking of removing some tests from my test suite. I don't think it'll lead to code being untested, but I'm not certain. Are there any tools that would enable me to identify code that's tested by the tests I want to remove, but not by anything else?

Comment: Why don't you remove the tests, run coverage report and see if it's decreased? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Ruby 1.9 how about [SimpleCov](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov)?